# How to assign an ienumerable object to a list in C#

Tags: c#

I have a method(method A) that returns an Ienumerable object.

The object is a datacontract class that has the following fields:

```
Id
TotalViews
```

I have another method(method B) that call calls Method A

Method A has the following:

```
List<string> response;
  
response = ExecuteRequest(uri).Select(d => new {d.Id, d.TotalViews }).ToList();
```

I trying to assign the ienumerable object to a list.

The above does not work as I get errors.

> Error
>
> cannot implicitly convert type system.collections.generic.list to system.collections.generic.list

How do I assign all the Ienumerable object to a list?

Answer (score 4):

You can't - because the result isn't a list of *strings*.

You could *convert* it to a list of strings, e.g.

```
List<string> response = ExecuteRequest(uri)
                              .Select(d => new {d.Id, d.TotalViews }.ToString())
                              .ToList();
```

... but I doubt that's what you really want. You should ask yourself:

- Why did you originally declare `response` to be of type `List<string>`?
- What type do you *really* want?
- If you want a pair of Id / TotalViews as per the anonymous type, there are three options:

  - If you only need it to be strongly-typed within the method, you can stick with an anonymous type, and declare the variable with `var`
  - Otherwise... you could build your own type with `Id` and `TotalViews` properties...
  - ... or you could potentially use `Tuple<,>` if you're using .NET 4

Here's the version using an anonymous type:

```
// The compiler knows the type of response, but you can't express it in normal
// C#, because it's IEnumerable<X> where X is the anonymous type... which you
// can't specify the name of, because it's anonymous...
var response = ExecuteRequest(uri).Select(d => new {d.Id, d.TotalViews })
                                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have *declared* a list of string, but you are trying to *assign* a list of an anonymous type. You could choose one of these options:

- Change the **declaration** to match the type you are trying to assign (in this case, an anonymous type):

  ```
  var response = ExecuteRequest(uri).Select(d => new {d.Id, d.TotalViews }).ToList();
  ```

Note that you can't return an anonymous type from a method.

- Change the **type that you are trying to assign** to match the declaration (in this case, `List<string>`):

  ```
  response = ExecuteRequest(uri).Select(d =>
          string.Format("{0} {1}", d.Id, d.TotalViews)
      ).ToList();
  ```
- Change **both**. Maybe a `Dictionary<int, int>` would be better for your needs?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to stuff an anonymous type made from `d.Id` and `d.TotalViews` into a list of strings.

Either create a string from both of these before calling `ToList` on the result, or create a containing class for these and make a list of those instead of a `String`.

```
public class TotalViewsPerId
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int TotalViews {get;set;}
}

List<TotalViewsPerId> response = ExecuteRequest(uri)
                              .Select(d => new TotalViewsPerId{d.Id, d.TotalViews })
                              .ToList();
```